# Why my graph from achartengine is initially show zoomed?

Tags: android, achartengine

When I use data sample from example code, all works fine.

```
Date[] dateValues = new Date[] { new Date(95, 0, 1), new Date(95, 3, 1), new Date(95, 6, 1),
                new Date(95, 9, 1), new Date(96, 0, 1), new Date(96, 3, 1), new Date(96, 6, 1),
                new Date(96, 9, 1), new Date(97, 0, 1), new Date(97, 3, 1), new Date(97, 6, 1),
                new Date(97, 9, 1), new Date(98, 0, 1), new Date(98, 3, 1), new Date(98, 6, 1),
                new Date(98, 9, 1), new Date(99, 0, 1), new Date(99, 3, 1), new Date(99, 6, 1),
                new Date(99, 9, 1), new Date(100, 0, 1), new Date(100, 3, 1), new Date(100, 6, 1),
                new Date(100, 9, 1), new Date(100, 11, 1) };
        dates.add(dateValues);
        double[] valueValues = { 4.9, 5.3, 3.2, 4.5, 6.5, 4.7, 5.8, 4.3, 4, 2.3, -0.5, -2.9, 3.2, 5.5,
                4.6, 9.4, 4.3, 1.2, 0, 0.4, 4.5, 3.4, 4.5, 4.3, 4 };
        values.add(valueValues);
```

But when I'm trying to use my own data, graph is painted particulary.

```
Set<Date> st = data.keySet();
Iterator<Date> it = st.iterator();
Date[] dateValues = new Date[data.size()]; 
double[] valueValues = new double[data.size()];
for (short i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    Date temp = it.next();
    dateValues[i] = temp;
    valueValues[i] = data.get(temp);
}

dates.add(dateValues);
values.add(valueValues);
```

I mean only central part, like graph is zoomed in.

[What I see in my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nb5eP.png)

Instead of [what I want to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdvMY.png)

```
double ymin = getYMin(valueValues) - (getYMax(valueValues) - getYMin(valueValues)) * 0.1;
        double ymax = getYMax(valueValues) + (getYMax(valueValues) - getYMin(valueValues)) * 0.1;
        int[] colors = new int[] { Color.GREEN };
        PointStyle[] styles = new PointStyle[] { PointStyle.POINT };
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildRenderer(colors, styles);
        setChartSettings(renderer, name, xtitle, ytitle, dateValues[0].getTime(),
            dateValues[dateValues.length - 1].getTime(), ymin, ymax, Color.GRAY, Color.LTGRAY);
        renderer.setShowGrid(true);
        renderer.setYLabels(5);
        renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        renderer.setZoomEnabled(true, false);
        renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
```

Comment: have you seen this http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/renderer/XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.html#setInitialRange%28double[]%29?

Comment: @hotveryspicy yes, I tried it, but no effect. Data from example is showing right. My own data - zoomed in.

Answer (score 2):

By default, AChartEngine calculates the best range for your data to be displayed. This means that it tries to display all your data on the screen. However, you can tweak this using:

```
renderer.setXAxisMin();
renderer.setXAxisMax();
renderer.setYAxisMin();
renderer.setYAxisMax();
```

Comment: 'renderer.setAxisMinMax()' is already implemented in 'setChartSettings()' method of extended abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. My Date data was unsorted. After I sorted it graph is showing ok.